# Why did the author assume there exist three connected components for $G\setminus u$?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

Why did the author assume there exist three connected components for $G\setminus u$?. In the statement of the theorem, it is not given. Can you explain why did the author use the underlined statement?

Comment: $v$ is in some component. The author is only using the fact that there is some other component of $G-u$ not containing $v$.

Answer (score 1):

The drawing has three components, but the wording of the proof only assumes there are at least two (one containing $v$, and at least one not containing $v$). There are at least two because we've assumed (for contradiction) that $u$ is a cut vertex, and that's what "cut vertex" means.